# TypeLoadException using PostgreSQL with ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, npgsql

I am attempting to use PostgreSQL as the data store for user authentication in an ASP.NET Core 1.0 Visual Studio 2015 project following installation of VS2015 Update 3 and the Core 1.0 release.

Steps:

1. Create new "ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework)" project.
2. Add NuGet packages "Npgsql" v3.1.4 and "Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" v1.0.0-rc2-release1
3. Modify ConfigureServices() in Startup.cs as follows:

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       // Add framework services.
       services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
           .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
           options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

       services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
           .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
           .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

       services.AddMvc();

       // Add application services.
       services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
       services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
   }
   ```
4. Run
5. Exception thrown on call to AddDbContext():

> An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in MyApp.exe
>   but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions.ServiceCollectionExtensions'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

I assume this is a compatibility issue that will soon be addressed in Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL, but wanted to confirm this and determine if a workaround is available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE:**  [This has been fixed](https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/issues/56).

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1171) on github, it will be fixed soon.

> 6/29/2016
>
> FYI 3.1.5 is out, targeting .NET Core RTM. The EFCore provider isn't
> out yet, that will take another day or two.